# Connect to hp photosmart 5510 series using wireless

Tags: hp, iwlwifi

I want to connect to hp photosmart 5510 using wireless.
How can I connect to hp photosmart 5510 using intel's wireless or download it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well @zixuan, you will have to find drivers for Linux that are designed for this machine...

With this being said, a quick search has turned up support for this printer on Linux. This is not the only good news though... The drivers were made by HP which is another plus...

Anyways, just go ahead and check the site out [here](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing) and follow the instructions for installation for Linux on the site.